# Problema al publicar aplicación NetCore con Angular en IIS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Buen día he realizado dos pruebas para publicar una aplicacion de NetCore 2.1 que utiliza la plantilla de angular, ya he realizado el deploy de angular desde comando build --prod y esta la carpeta 'dist' en mi proyecto,sin embargo al tratar de publicarlo desde visualstudio manda error,en otraq maquina mandó otro similar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cabe mencionar que este equipo tengo instalado Nodejs y phyton de forma independiente, tendrá que estar integrado como ambiente angular/cli ?

Comment: el problema parece ser mas de python, no se encuentra en los paths

Comment: ya reinstalé NodeJS,Phyton 2.7 desde el ejecutable de sitio oficial , ejecuté VS como administrador, Para publicar :configuracion Realease,el modo de implementación independiente y continúa el mismo , busca python 2

Comment: He probado en Windows10,según recomiendan en otro hijo de stack usando --global windows-build-tools, teniéndolo en un disco externo el proyecto avanza un poco la compilación y luego se produce un error de node-sass. Por ultimo opté copiando el proyecto a la unidad C: y ejecutar los mismos pasos y solamente ahí funciona por las rutas que toman las dependencias js

Answer (score 0):

bueno ahí hay dos cosas a tomar en cuenta.

1. Que el proyecto angular tenga las herramientas de compilación:
   se elimina el node_modules y se ejecuta
   `npm install --global windows-build-tools`; dentro del cliente angular(ésto agregará ese python2 independiente de la instalación global);enseguida se reinstala `npm install`.
   2)El perfil de publicación debe ser correcto:
   En Configuración de la solución se establece release y se crea un perfil de publicación preferente que coincida con version de SO(x86 o x64) y un modo de implementación :dependiente del marco de trabajo

Comment: @AlonsoCastañeda esta seria la respuesta? así solucionaste el problema, a mi Tambien me sucede lo mismo. cuando haces esto no me puede dañar npm global?

Comment: @ger asi es amigo,